# ¿Como puedo acceder a un objeto dentro de un array en php?

Tags: php, laravel, array, foreach

Tengo el siguiente array.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando acceder a la propiedad name del objeto person, como podría hacerlo?. De momento he intentado con lo siguiente, pero no me funciona.

```
foreach ($deliveryMan as $del) {
    foreach ($del->delivery_man as $d) {
        print_r($d);
    }
}
```

Comment: $deliveryMan[0]->delivery_man->person

Comment: Ya lo he intentado de esa manera, pero me arroja el siguiente error: Trying to get property 'person' of non-object.

Comment: Imposible, segun el array que muestras en imagen deberias de ingresar a person de esa manera, si aun asi el error esta, deberias de editar tu pregunta, y quiza mostrar la consulta que tienes para sacar dicho resultado.

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer para acceder a la propiedad que quieres, es hacer debug del tipo de objeto que obtienes al explorar array en el foreach, puedes usar gettype para saber que tipo de dato está identificando PHP y posteriormente accederlo de la manera correcta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los array y los objetos se manipulan de formas distintas en PHP

Para los arrays se puede usar

```
$array['valor'];
```

Mientras que para los objetos es

```
$array->valor;
```

El problema que estas enfrentando es que lo que tenes que manipular no es un array, es un array de JSONs.

**Para esto primero deberemos decodificarlo**

```
$array = json_decode($array, true)
```

Te recomiendo usar el json_decode con el parametro true para que te devuelva un array associativo, estos son mucho mas faciles de manipular.
Igualmente al final te voy a dejar como hacerlo con stdClass

El segundo paso es manipularlo como un array normal

```
$array['delivery_man']['person']['name'];
```

Proximamente cuando agreges mas elementos a este array deberas hacer:

```
$array[0]['delivery_man']['person']['name'];
```

Donde 0 es el id del registro

*Si no te funciona dejame en un comentario tu json e intentare replicarlo.*

*Aca te dejo como hacerlo con objetos por si preferis usar stdClass*

```
json_decode($array);

$array->0->delivery_man->person->name
```